# python image to number avoiding ocr

Tags: python, image, preprocessor, ocr

I have the following problem. A range of images should be assigned to numbers as soon as they appear. I made several attempts to ocr the images but failed. Is there a simpler solution? If I take a certain position from the screen (coordinates are always the same) process the pixels with some function and map a number manually to the output of the function as soon as the specific pixel pattern is found I get the same result. How would I do that in Python? Maybe with PIL?

Best, US

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this would be classified as OCR, there are many out of the box Python machine learning libraries that may be useful to do the ocr for you, especially if you labelled examples of the digits. Take a look at http://scikit-learn.sourceforge.net/stable/auto_examples/plot_digits_classification.html, which may be what you need.